# Getting a total amount from a column for Month/Year for each user

Tags: mysql

I've got a Table called AdslAccount and in this table theres a few columns

userName, downloadMb, date (and a few more but they aren't relevant)
It looks like this

```
user1, 20, 10-10-2013  
user2, 12, 10-10-2013  
user2, 12, 09-10-2013  
user1, 13, 09-10-2013  
user2, 12, 09-09-2013  
user1, 13, 09-09-2013
```

Now what I want with a Query is a list of all users with their total downloadMb per MONTH (taking in account that there are more 09's and 10's in different years)

I've tried many MANY queries but none did what I want.
Could someone guide me in the right direction or perhaps provide me with a correct query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select userName, CONCAT(YEAR(date), MONTH(date)), SUM(downloadMb) from AdslAccount
group by userName, CONCAT(YEAR(date), MONTH(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate myself a bit for this, but ...

```
SELECT `userName`, SUM(`downloadMb`) AS downloadMb, SUBSTR(`date`, 4) AS month FROM `AdslAccount` GROUP BY 3
```

Comment: Wont this one calculate the total for months regardless of year?

Comment: No. It'll get you the total by month *and* year as `SUBSTR(date,4)` will return something like `MM-YYYY`.